# How to allow user to use backspace key to exit back to main_menu.sh depending whether user calls it directly

Tags: bash, enter, backspace

My plan is to have a menu of menus.

so I will have a main_menu.sh and 2 sub menus: menu1.sh and menu2.sh

in the main_menu.sh I am following the code example from this [example](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Menu_driven_scripts)

So in the main_menu when I press 1 I call menu1.sh like this:

```
one() {
  bash menu1.sh
  pause
}
```

and so on.

Inside menu1.sh it also uses the same structure as main_menu.sh

My purpose is

in the main_menu.sh there's a pause function

```
pause(){
  read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue..." fackEnterKey
}
```

What I want is when the user calls menu1.sh via main_menu.sh, the pause function inside menu1.sh can read two possible characters. Either Enter key or Backspace key.

Pressing Backspace key inside menu1.sh during the menu1's pause will then leave the menu1.sh and go back to main_menu.sh

Pressing Enter key inside menu1.sh during the menu1's pause will then continue inside menu1.sh.

However, i also want it such that the user can call menu1.sh as a standalone bash script command using `bash menu1.sh`

When that happens, the pause function inside menu1.sh no longer takes in the backspace key since strictly speaking there's no main_menu.sh to go to.

How do I write my main_menu.sh and menu1.sh to allow this kind of behavior?

Comment: You could try the `-e` flag from the builtin `read`, to show it's meaning `help read  | grep -- ' -e'`

Comment: I'm afraid Bash might not be a suitable environment for what you appear to be trying to create. Perhaps look at some Curses interface builder if you want it to run on text-only terminals, or build a GUI if not.

Comment: I did a menu with sub-menus and built it all in one script, not call other bash scripts for sub-menus.  It was easier to move from menu to sub-menu.

Comment: Ok thanks everyone. I figured out how to have loosely coupled menu bash scripts that can kinda join up like Voltron or work as standalone. I realized asking abt backspace is a bit of a XY problem. I will clean up my existing solution and post it as answer over the weekends. Thank you everyone